# Qt fastest way to add QVector elements to QStack , avoiding loop

Tags: qt, vector, stack

i have main

```
QStack<TypeFoo*> MainStack
```

now i have from different objects methods output

```
QVector<TypeFoo*> OutPutVec
```

i like to add the elements of OutPutVec to MainStack without looping , just add them to the bottom if the stack , what is the best way to do this ? do i need to convert my OutPutVec
to QStack?

is this good and fast more then loop ?

```
QVector<T> & QVector::operator+= ( const QVector<T> & other )
```

Comment: Any specific reason to want to avoid looping?

Comment: to much of them allready .. any way i think i found something
QVector<T> & QVector::operator+= ( const QVector<T> & other )

Comment: Keep in mind that this will use a loop internally anyway, and it won't be faster than just using a loop. The only reason to prefer it would be for style, and making your code easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QStack](http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qstack.html) inherits [QVector](http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qvector.html) and QVector has the following definition:

> QVector &  operator<< ( const QVector & other )

Therefore you should be able to simply do

```
MainStack << OutPutVec;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use operator `<<` for append containers.
You can choose one of the variant.

This is realisation of operator `+=`

```
template <typename T>
QVector<T> &QVector<T>::operator+=(const QVector &l)
{
    int newSize = d->size + l.d->size;
    realloc(d->size, newSize);

    T *w = p->array + newSize;
    T *i = l.p->array + l.d->size;
    T *b = l.p->array;
    while (i != b) {
        if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex)
            new (--w) T(*--i);
        else
            *--w = *--i;
    }
    d->size = newSize;
    return *this;
}
```

And realisation of operator `<<`

```
inline QVector<T> &operator<<(const QVector<T> &l)
{ *this += l; return *this; }
```

PS. Creating a loop to copy the data does not make sense, if you can use Qt "buns". Qt appends data faster, then your loop

PSS. If you read the assistant, you might find that the QStack is inherited from the QVector.